# MVC List of links

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm capturing an external URL (string) in a form.

I want to pass this string to a view but transform it into a clickable link.

Currently I'm using this in the view which of course is just going to display my string. How do I turn it into a link?

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Website)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<a href="@Model.Website">@Model.Website</a>
```

or for a list of urls:

```
@foreach(var url in Model.Websites)
{
     <a href="@url">@url</a>
}
```

Comment: Jamie, thanks. I'm still learning MVC..I appreciate the help!